# WSO2 EMM emm-agent-Android Agent compatibality with wso2 2.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am using wso2 emm version 2.2.0 and using EMM Agent Android version 3.0.3. Users complaint on frequent disconnect and require re enrollment. Sometimes reenrollment also fails. Is it advisable using a different version agent with EMM server? What is the implication on doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not advisable to use incompatible versions of WSO2 client and server.

You can check compatibility in the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM330/WSO2+IoT+Server+and+Agent+Compatibility)